# check point, checkpoint or check-point

Tags: hyphenation

I am an English Editor for a journal and came across the following sentence in a paper I was editing:

> ...the increase amount will be doubled at every check point.

The context is Cloud-Based Virtual Content Delivery Networks and so the word 'check point' is not a physical entity. My question is should it be 'check point', 'checkpoint' or 'check-point'?

I cannot find many uses of the word 'check-point' and do not know the rule or reason as to why it would be hyphenated.

Can anyone help me with this matter?

Answer (score 3):

Checkpoint does not need to be hyphenated, nor is it two words.

The OED (Oxford English Dictionary) lists it as a single word in both its British English and US English versions.

Although it is in a relatively new context — network technology — its meaning is still much the same, simply, from this example, it refers to a point where a check will be carried out.

So, edit it into a single word.